# Proof for the equivalence between a quotient ring and a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Can someone give me an idea, how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I=\mathbb{Q}[\hat{x}]$,
where $I$ is the ideal generated by $-1+x+x^{2}$ and $\hat{x}$
is the equivalence of $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ ?

I know some facts about $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ (it is a field, since the
polynomial is irreducible etc.), but my problem is that we did so much
theory in class the I literally can't see the forest for the trees.
I tried applying the proof from theorem 3 from page 512 from Dummit
\& Foote's {}``Abstract Algebra'', but somehow I couldn't get it
to work, because my hunch to solve this problem was to use the evaluation
homomorphism, but plugging an equivalance class of polynomials into
a polynomial itself is just extremely confusing.

Comment: A naive way of answering the question: The element $\widehat x$ satisfies $-1+\widehat x+\widehat x^2=0$ and **nothing else**. --- It seems to me the present question is very similar to [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/97336/660) of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E \hookrightarrow F$ be a field extension, fix $x_0 \in F$. Consider in $E[x]$ the collection $V$ of polynomials such that evaluating at $x_0$ yields 0, this is easily seen to be an ideal (if it's nonempty). In particular, $V = (p)$, by considering polynomials in $V$ of the smallest degree.

As you say, we have $ev: E[x] \twoheadrightarrow E[x_0]$, and quotienting out by the kernel we have by the first isomorphism theorem $E[x]/(p) \simeq E[x_0]$.

So for your question, you just have to note that $-1 + x + x^2$ is irreducible, and hence is the $p$ (up to fiddling with multiplication by units) as above. Done!